# How to enable scroll in iOS 7 storyboard no matter what orientation?

Tags: ios, orientation, scrollview

I developing my first iOS app; I have 2 view controllers, one with a login form and the other with a register form. The issue that I am facing is that when I hold the phone horizontally the can't see the whole form!!! What i tried to do is in the following video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Knw41Tz_M

my h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
}
- (IBAction)buttonGoBackToLogin:(id)sender;
.....
```

my m file:

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
...
```

I did add the **Scroll View** Object to the storybored view controller and I did drag and drop the **Scroller** under the **outlet** in the **connection inspector**. But I still cant scroll !! any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable autolayout

[image]

Thad solved the issue but now the form fields need rearranging

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realized that the `contentView` of the scroll view was `CGRectZero` in `viewDidAppear`. I solved it be setting the `contentSize` in `viewDidAppear`.